# zf2 validate uri - unexpected results

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, uri

I need to evaluate the uri but neither the validator Hostname nor Uri help me .
maybe something's septum properly.

use the following code

```
$oHostnameValidator = new Hostname(array('allow'=>Hostname::ALLOW_URI));
if(!$oHostnameValidator->isValid($value)){
  $this->error(self::ER_WEB);
  return false;
}
```

the result that i want should be

```
http://www.example.com      >>      true
www.example.com             >>      true
example.com                 >>      true

example                     >>      false
example.                    >>      false
```

but i get

```
http://www.example.com      >>      false   >>      wrong
www.example.com             >>      true
example.com                 >>      true

example                     >>      true    >>      wrong
example.                    >>      true    >>      wrong
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're validating a hostname. "http://www.example.com" is not a valid hostname. "example" is a valid hostname.

It does exactly what you want. "http://" is not part of the hostname, so that is correct. "example" is also a valid hostname (just like "localhost" is).

You should be using a URI helper to grab the hostname from a URI, then validate that with the hostname validator.

I've recently worked on a URI helper that might help you out: http://packagist.org/packages/enrise/urihelper